# Saving common data for fixtures in Doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, fixtures

What are the best-practice ways to keep the common data for the fixtures? Something like users. One entity contain id, another entity firstname and lastname, third entity another data related with user. Then number of users is growing up, number of entities and data in entities growing up too and voila - for adding user in fixtures i edit +100500 files.
Is exist some common way except one static class with all related data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [Nelmio\Alice](https://github.com/nelmio/alice). 
There you can save data fixtures to .yaml files.

It uses fzaninotto\Faker and Doctrine\DataFixtures.

If you use Symfony, there is [AliceBundle](https://github.com/hautelook/AliceBundle/).